# Inserting data in SQL Server table not showing error on both condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have use procedure to insert data into table for fixed column size. But data trim and inserted successfully without any error.

I have lost some content from that variable.

This code snippet is **not** showing any error:

```
declare @temp varchar(5)
declare @tm table (a varchar(5))
set @temp ='abcdefghijkl'

insert into @tm 
values(@temp)

select * from @tm
```

But this code snippet **is** showing this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

```
declare @temp1 varchar(5)
declare @tm1 table (a varchar(5))

insert into @tm1 
values('abcdefghijkl')

select * from @tm1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the second code snippet is raising an error is a good thing.
It prevents you from corrupting data by mistake.

In the first code snippet, however, SQL Server will silently trim the string due to implicit conversion rules.
Whenever you attempt to populate a variable with a data that has a different data type, SQL Server will attempt to implicitly convert the data type to the data type of the variable.

This is well documented in the [Converting Character Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#_character) section of the char and varchar (Transact-SQL) page:

> When character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated.

This does not happen when inserting into a table, providing [`ANSI_WARNINGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is set to `ON` (which is the default state).
When `ANSI_WARNINGS` is set to `ON`, you get the

> String or binary data would be truncated

error message.
When it's set to `OFF`, however, the implicit conversion will silently truncate the data:

```
set ansi_warnings off;

declare @temp1 varchar(5)
declare @tm1 table (a varchar(5))

insert into @tm1 
values('abcdefghijkl')

select * from @tm1
```

Result:

```
a
abcde
```

**Note:** The `ansi_warnings` state does not have effect the implicit conversion when setting a variable value - it will always be truncated regardless of the `ansi_warnings` state.

Comment: It's working but for first snippet  when use variable to insert. It's not showing warning. Data has been trim as per table column size.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've tried to explain why this is happening in my answer.

Comment: But any solution to use in procedure to get this warning and data not trim to store into table.

Comment: You can test the length of the string before assigning it to the variable - `if len(<string here>) > <variable length here>` raise error.